# Anyone Getting Bad Printouts from 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, evince

For several years I have been downloading credit card statements as pdf files. I then print them, before inputting the info to gnucash. I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 yesterday. Now if I try to print one of these files, in most instances a quantity prefaced by a $-sign is messed up. What happens, is the $-sign overwrites the first digit of the number.

I tried to report this as a bug, but it seems to be nearly impossible to report a bug if the application has not crashed.

Has anyone else noticed this bug? If so, do you know if it has been reported?

Comment: If this is a bug, this question should be closed as off topic.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue - couldn't see it in the evince bug list but have asked a question on Launchpad, see:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+question/218163

I am currently getting around the problem by first printing to .ps or .svg file and then printing again from there, although the margins are smaller by default.